# How to search in directory and save in database many records - php error

Tags: php

I'm trying to search in a directory some images by offer and then insert them in database. But first, images in directory are many - 35000 and I should search in this directory for all offers - that are 10000.
It's showing error:

> maximum execution time exceeded in 30 sec

How should I do that?

I'm searching by pattern - by $segment - that is offer id:

```html
if ($dh = opendir($dir))
{
    $array = array();
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {
        $s = substr($file, strpos($file, $segment), strlen($segment));
        if($s == $segment) {
            $array[] = $file;
        }

        foreach($array as $key) {
            $sql = new sql();

            $sql->query("INSERT INTO offers_images(offer_id, offer_filename) Values ('".$segment."', '".$key."') ");
        }

        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For first, like easy way: You can try use **set_time_limit(0)** but this option may be disabled on shared hosting. You must check it.

2) You can make separated multiple "workers" or one "worker" like step by step for small pieces of data.

3) You can write php script for CLI mode (these unlimited time) and run it as background job.

Comment: Where should I set set_time_limit(0) - I want to try it?

Comment: It's working, now it's inserting in database and no php error! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try searching them by a pattern

(that way you'll filter to less files).

Follow link:
[glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)